# Making 'pushd' directory stack persistent

Tags: bash, pushd, cwd

Ok this is a short question. I just happened to know that with `pushd` command, we can add more working directories into our list, which is handy. But is there a way to make this list permanent, so it can survive reboots or logoffs?

Comment: Well you can write a little script to be ran at log in to accomplish that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may pre-populate the directory stack in your `~/.bashrc` file if you wish:

```
for dir in "$HOME/dir" /usr/src /usr/local/lib; do
    pushd -n "$dir" >/dev/null
end
```

or, if you want to put the directories in an array and use them from there instead:

```
dirstack=( "$HOME/dir"
           /usr/src
           /usr/local/lib )

for dir in "${dirstack[@]}"; do
    pushd -n "$dir" >/dev/null
end

unset dirstack
```

With `-n`, `pushd` won't actually change the working directory, but instead just add the given directory to the stack.

If you wish, you can store the value of the `DIRSTACK` array (upper-case variable name here), which is the *current* directory stack, into a file from `~/.bash_logout`, and then read that file in `~/.bashrc` rather than using a predefined array.

In `~/.bash_logout`:

```
declare -p DIRSTACK >"$HOME/.dirstack"
```

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.dirstack" ]; then
    source "$HOME/.dirstack"
fi
```

I don't know how well this would work in a situation where you use multiple terminals. The `.dirstack` file would be overwritten every time a terminal exited, if it ran a `bash` as a login shell.