# Why doesn't the directory stack persist from inside a script?

Tags: shell-script

I was working on a script to set up a project-specific environment.  I created a script to set up the directory stack as suggested in the first comment to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365339/making-pushd-directory-stack-persistent).  Console output provided evidence that the stack was being created as designed, but as the script completed, the stack did not exist when I was returned to the console.

I suspect that this is a design feature to allow the script writer an independent environment, and that this touches on a question of broader scope concerning how the environment is handled inside and outside of a script.  What is going on and where can I learn more?

Comment: Did you *run* the script or *source* it?

Comment: I ran the script.

Comment: ... so try sourcing it instead - see relate [Script to change current directory (cd, pwd)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd)

Comment: Source seems to do the job.  That gives me a hint on where to look next.

Comment: This tells me that the difference that source executes in the current chell process, while executing starts a new process:  https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it

Comment: As this is due to the same reason `cd` (or changing the current environment in other ways) in a script that is run in a separate child process can't affect the parent shell's environment, I'm closing this as a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd